# Resolving simple references in a spreadsheet structure. Is this a linked list problem?

Tags: arrays, linked-list

I have this job test task where I am need some help.

I have to somehow dynamically access the value in the data stucture below,  through references. To this point I used loops and `indexOf()` in an ordered alphabet and numbers. `indexOf("B")` in alphabet is `[[ 1 ]]`, `indexOf(1)` is `[0]` for the two dimensional array.

Here "B1" is referencing "C1", "C1" references "D1" .. to "H1" and when "H1" points to the text "Last", all of the formulas should turn into the same value - the text "Last".

But how? Been breaking my head for a couple of hours and remembered linked lists, but so far have no clue how to implement them. How can I achieve this?

```
{ 
    data: [
      [
        { reference: "B1" }, 
        { reference: "C1" }, 
        { reference: "D1" }, 
        { reference: "E1" }, 
        { reference: "F1" }, 
        { reference: "G1" }, 
        { reference: "H1" }, 
        { text: "Last" }, 
      ]
    ],
    id: "job-20"
}
```

Comment: Please don't post text as images, but as text (formatted as code using toolbar). Can you better explain what the desired output is for this input? *"indexOf(B) in alphabet is [ 1 ], indexOf(1) is [0] for the two dimensional array."*: I really don't understand what you are saying here.

Comment: Sorry about the image. B1 how the access works. As you can see there is two dimensional array. Like in an Excel file. So B is column and 1 is row. If you take B, it's position in alphabet array is 1. And index of number 1 in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0] is 0. So, B1 refers to [0][1]. Based on this, I have to read the last part - the value. Is it any clearer?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to work with a spreadsheet type of data structure, and need to recalculate cells based on the formulas they have.

You can use recursion for that.

The base case happens when you arrive at a cell that has no reference. In that case the text of that cell can be returned to the caller. And that caller will assign that text to the cell it was looking at, and also returns that to *their* caller...etc.

```js
function get(reference) { // return the cell object at the given reference
  return data[reference.slice(1)-1][reference.charCodeAt() - "A".charCodeAt()];
}

function resolve(cell, visited=new Set) {
  // Have we found a cell with just text? Then return that to caller
  if (!("reference" in cell)) return cell.text;
  // Did we already meet this cell before? Then we are running in circles!
  if (visited.has(cell)) return "Circular Reference!";
  // Make a recursive call to know what the text should be
  cell.text = resolve(get(cell.reference), visited.add(cell));
  delete cell.reference;
  return cell.text; // Return this value also to the caller
}

function calculate(data) {
  // Get to each cell object...
  for (let row of data) {
    for (let cell of row) {
      resolve(cell); // And update its text property by following references
    }
  }
}

let data = [
  [
    {reference: "B1"}, {reference: "C1"}, {reference: "D1"}, {reference: "E1"}, 
    {reference: "F1"}, {reference: "G1"}, {reference: "H1"}, {text: "Last"}, 
  ]
];

calculate(data);
console.log(data);
```

It should be noted that in a real spreadsheet the references (formulas) are not deleted during such a recalculation. The cell will have *both* the text and the reference, so that when a cell's text is updated, all other dependent cells get their own text updated accordingly *again*.

Comment: You totally got the idea, I just need to overwrite the formula, put the text instead of it. I'm still trying to figure out your code but it definitely is useful and leading me onto the right path, thank you.

Comment: You mean the reference property should be deleted? Can you edit your question and add the desired output in object notarion?

Comment: Yes, the reference property should be deleted and replaced with that text value. Instead of {reference: H1}, there finally should be {text: "Last"}. I assume it's the visited.add part but don't see the recursion in it yet.

Senior sir, you're amazing (bow).

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly.